# Problems in writing a file using Map<String, Map<String, Long>>

Tags: java, string, file, hash, hashmap

I have a data structure in the following format `Map<String, Map<String, Long>> map`:

`1987   {abacate=1, catuaba, lion=3, coco=1, asas=2}
2005    {Polymer Science=3}
1234    {Environmental Studies=1}`

Where each **year** is the key to my Hash and each pair `word=number` corresponds to an earlier operation which I counted the occurrences of this word (the ones separate with a comma are one single term).

I'm trying to iterate through this hash so I can have every pair `word=number` separated with a delimiter, but due to this structure my results are not very consistent.

When I was using a simple `Map<String, List<String>>` I could iterate and recover all my keys and values without any problem. Using `map.forEach()` I was able to do that

```
map.forEach((name, lines) -> {
    try {
        Files.write(Paths.get(PATH), lines);`
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.getStackTrace();
    }
});
```

But now in this structure I'm getting trouble. Does anyone have a good approach to go through this structure (`Map<String, Map<String, Long>>`) so I can write it using a a delimiter?

Comment: Thank you @Dan W for fixing my format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may just want to iterate through the Maps without lambdas to understand what you want to do.

```
    Map<String, Map<String, Long>> map = new HashMap<>();

    //...

    for (Entry<String, Map<String, Long>> mapEntry : map.entrySet()) {
        String mapKey = mapEntry.getKey();
        Map<String, Long> submap = mapEntry.getValue();
        for (Entry<String, Long> submapEntry : submap.entrySet()) {
            String submapKey = submapEntry.getKey();
            Long submapList = submapEntry.getValue();

            //TODO: do whatever you want with these items.
        }
    }
```

Comment: Great idea, I tried to compact my code and it was a mess.
I shall try your approach @Chill

Comment: my data is on Map<String, Map<String, Long>>, I'm trying to adapt your code, but it is saying that my structure is not iterateble. I suppose it is very similar to yours, but the entry map would be my structure right ?

Comment: My `Map<String, List<String>>` was transformed into the following     `Map<String, Map<String, Long>> props = count_hash_feat_rep.entrySet().stream().collect(toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, e -> e.getValue().stream().collect(groupingBy(String::toString, counting()))));`
So when I try to use your for it does not recognize my `props` as a valid type for this operation

Comment: I missed `.entrySet()` in the for loops.

Comment: Nice, let me try again.

Comment: Even with that, it seems `incompatible types: Entry<String,Map<String,Long>> cannot be converted to Entry<String,Map<String,List<String>>>` my map is in the `Map<String, Map<String, Long>>` structure. I will try to adapt to see if it works

Comment: Thanks. I post my modification here just in case someone needs.

`for (Entry<String, Map<String, Long>> mapEntry : props.entrySet()) {
            String mapKey = mapEntry.getKey();
            Map<String, Long> submap = mapEntry.getValue();
            for (Entry<String, Long> submapEntry : submap.entrySet()) {
                String submapKey = submapEntry.getKey();
                Long submapList = submapEntry.getValue();

                System.out.println(mapKey + "\t" + submapKey + "\t" + submapList);
                //TODO: do whatever you want with these items.
            }
        }`

Answer (score 0):

Small variation of @Chill response (all credits to him)

```
for (Entry<String, Map<String, Long>> mapEntry : props.entrySet()) {
            String mapKey = mapEntry.getKey();
            Map<String, Long> submap = mapEntry.getValue();
            for (Entry<String, Long> submapEntry : submap.entrySet()) {
                String submapKey = submapEntry.getKey();
                Long submapList = submapEntry.getValue();

                System.out.println(mapKey + "\t" + submapKey + "\t" + submapList);
                //TODO: do whatever you want with these items.
            }
        }
```

My data is in a `Map <String, Map<String, Long>>` , so I modified his code a little.